# How to insert data from model to table in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am trying to  insert into the table from a model  but I am getting the following error.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO user_sample(user_id) VALUES(?); sampleid]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sampleid' at line
```

Here is my code:

```
public class UserInfo {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_sample` (
  `user_partner_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_partner_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=77182 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the code to insert data into the table.

```
public void insertValues(@ModelAttribute USerInfo userInfo){
  jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO user_sample(user_id) VALUES(?)", userInfo.getId());
  }
```

what statement to use to insert data from a model ?

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot you don't need to write your inserts `manually`, just leverage the power of JPA: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it that kind of way I suggest you use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`
There is an example so you can see how easy it is:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
...

@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTmpl;
....

public void insertValues(@ModelAttribute USerInfo userInfo){
  StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
  sql.append("INSERT INTO user_sample(user_id) ");
  sql.append("VALUES(:userId) ");

  Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  params.put("userId", userInfo.getId());

  jdbcTmpl.update(sql.toString(), params);
}
```